# Are there situations where it makes sense to store redundant data in a database, to increase speed?

Tags: database, relational-database

In the following situation:

```
user has many bags
bag has many items

users
-id

bags
-id
-user_id

items
-id
-bag_id
```

There are 2 ways to get access to a user's items.

1) An instance method can be added to a user, which iterates over each of the user's bags, and collects the bag's items into an array to return. In Ruby on Rails, something like:

```
#in user.rb
def items
    items = []
    bags.includes(:items).each { |bag| items += bag.items }
end
```

2) Add a `user_id` attribute directly to the items table, and add an additional relationship, so that `user has many items`. Then just do `user.items`.

The 2nd method would be faster, but involves storing redundant data. Are there situations where it makes sense to implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are certain circumstances where it does make sense to introduce some controlled redundancy for the sake of performance. Generally, this should only be done when a database is unable to meet its performance requirements. This is called "denormalisation" and what you have to consider is that it:

- Can make implementation more complex
- Often sacrifices flexibility
- May speed up retrievals but slow down updates (as you now have to update more than one location)

So it's something to consider in cases where performance is unsatisfactory and a relation has a low update rate and high query rate.

There are also some denormalised database designs, such as the star schema, which are used in database warehousing.

Comment: Be aware that if you denormalize, you MUST use triggers to make sure the denormalized data stays in synch, otherwise you will have data integrity problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In particular, reporting databases, data marts and data warehouses often use design principles that knowingly depart from some of the normalization rules.  The result is a database that has some redundancy in it, but is not only faster to query, but easier as well.

Ease of query is particularly important when there is an analytic GUI between the database and the database user.  These analytic tools are quite a bit easier to master if certain design principles are followed in database design.  Normalization isn't particularly helpful in this regard.

Unnormalized design need not mean undisciplined design.  In particular, it's worth boning up on star schema and snowflake schema designs if you plan on building a reporting database, a data mart, or a data warehouse. The process by which a star or snowflake schema is kept up to date, sometimes called ETL (extract-transform-load), has to be carefully written so as to prevent controlled redundancy from resulting in self contradictory data.

In transaction oriented databases, normalized is generally better, although many experts don't try to push it beyond Boyce-Codd normal form.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's something you haven't told us, a table like this

```
create table bagged_items (
  user_id integer not null,
  bag_id integer not null,
  item_id integer not null,
  primary key (user_id, bag_id, item_id)
);
```

is in at least 5NF. It's all key. There's not a bit of redundant data there.

What you've done isn't normalization; normalization is based on identifying certain kinds of dependencies, and reducing their effects by projection. And what you've done isn't denormalization, either; denormalization is an undoing of normalization.

You've simply split a primary key into pieces. I don't pretend to know what principle you followed in order to justify that. It *looks* a little like "no table may have more than one foreign key" normal form. (But, of course, there's no such thing.)

Answer (score 0):

For combining records from two SQL tables, databases implement efficient [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) methods that can be [used from Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables). For almost all applications this is fast enough. That being said, for certain high performances stores, you might want to store redundant data as you suggested, but this comes at the cost of having to keep the data in sync on writes.